# XML Character Encoding / Converter

Tags: xml, flash, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I've got a XML file (exported by a Flash software) with a "wrong" (actually it's wrong for my website) character encoding, e.g.

```
<label index="prename">%u0418%u043C%u044F</label>
```

instead of

```
<label index="prename">Имя</label>
```

Do you know a software, online tool or script for converting the XML file? The software should convert a string like %u0418%u043C%u044F to Имя. The XML has about 5.000 lines.

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: What programming language you want to use for encoding on the receiving side? Flash?

Comment: Hello Mark, I'm using PHP on the receiving side.